# How would one express $\tan(270+2\theta)$ , if tan theta is $3/4$?

Tags: trigonometry

I have been doing self-studies and finished the rest of the exercise besides this question.

Using the addition formula:

This turns into:

$$\frac{\tan(270)+\tan(\theta)}{1-\tan(270)\cdot\tan(\theta)}$$

This is where I get stuck.

$\tan(270) = \tan(90) = \pm \infty$ at the same time.

Is there a way to change $\tan(270)$ into something that is not infinity?

Answer (score 2):

Use the multiple angle and addition formulas
$$\tan(2z)=\frac{2\tan z}{1-\tan^{2} z}$$
$$\tan(z_1+z_2)=\frac{\tan z_1+\tan z_2}{1-\tan z_1\tan z_2}$$
Assuming degrees mode (not radian) you have with $\tan(135)=-1$ and $\tan \theta=3/4$

$$\tan(135+\theta)=\frac{-1+\tan\theta} {1+\tan\theta}=\frac{-1/4} {7/4}=-\frac{1}{7}$$
and therefore
$$\tan(270+2\theta)=\tan(2(135+\theta))=-\frac{2\cdot 1/7}{1-1/49}= -\frac{2/7}{48/49}=-\frac{7}{24}\approx -0.2916667$$

Comment: How do you derive $\tan135^\circ=-1$? (+1) though

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee: If you really find that necessary: E.g. from the elementary insight $\cos 45° = \sin 45° \ne 0$ and the relations $\cos(90°+x) = -\sin(x)\;$ and $\sin(90°+x) = \cos(x).$

Comment: Similarly, you can employ $\cos(270^\circ+2\theta)=\sin2\theta$ etc., right?

Answer (score 0):

$\tan(270+2\theta) = \tan(90 \cdot 4-(90- 2\theta))$ which is $\tan(2\theta-90)$  or $-\cot(2\theta)$ (we know $\tan(\theta) = 3/4$) so $$\cot(2\theta) = \dfrac{1}{\tan(2\theta)} = \frac{1}{\dfrac{24}{7}} = \frac{7}{24}$$ so answer is $-7/24$.

Comment: To obtain $\tan\theta$, type \tan\theta between dollar signs.